# How to use libvlc for android for streaming live videos

Tags: android, eclipse, video-streaming, libvlc

I'm very much confused. I need to stream video on my server in android app, but the problem I think with native *VideoView* of android is that it fails with videos with larger resolution and size. So I googled it and found that I need to use library by **VLC** for android to stream live videos. I have cloned *libvlc* but now It shows so many errors when I import libraries to my eclipse workspace. I've tried so many combinations by removing and adding different libraries but got nothing.

I also downloaded demo from here [bitbucket libvlc code sample](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample), but it is not working. please help me and if possible please provide link to any demo project.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see any error details provided, I'm going to guess your issue. `libvlc` source code by default does not include the actual vlc source code. If you run the `compile.sh` script in the repo with the needed flags/env variables for sdk/ndk, it should clone that source code for you. This process is meant to be done by command line, not eclipse. Other steps are needed to be done manually if not using those scripts. When the build finishes, there should be an .aar file in `libvlc/build/outputs/libvlc-x.x.x.aar` Then that sample app will be able to use the aar you built to work(per README).